# Sort array based on string transformed into date

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have an array containing reviews (which I retrieve from firebase firestore). The field 'date' is string in firestore. How can I sort the reviews in descending order based on this date? I have tried this but they are in the retrieval order.

```
const getReviews=async()=>{
        let reviewsClone=[];
        const q = query(collection(db, "reviews"), where("product", "==", uniqueProductName.product));
        const querySnapshot=await getDocs(q);
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc)=>{
            reviewsClone.push(doc.id);
        })

        reviewsClone.sort(function(a,b){
            return new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date);
          });
        setReviews(reviewsClone);

    }
```

Comment: What is the date format? Any example string?

Comment: If the string is in ISO format, you may want to user OrderBy in the firebase query instead.

Comment: the string is 'dd/mm/yyyy'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this? It's likely that you are sorting an array of strings `reviewsClone` currently, which all have `.date` prop undefined, therefore .sort has no effect.

```js
const getReviews=async()=>{
        let reviewsClone=[];
        const q = query(collection(db, "reviews"), where("product", "==", uniqueProductName.product));
        const querySnapshot=await getDocs(q);
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc)=>{
            reviewsClone.push(doc);
        })

        reviewsClone.sort(function(a,b){
            return new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date);
          });
        setReviews(reviewsClone.map(c => c.id));

    }
```

Comment: yes, I think you're right. but this still not works

Comment: It's not one error but several, then. Probably the answer above mine would help. Also check that `new Date(a.date)` and `new Date(b.date)` return correct dates indeed.

Comment: ok so I had to change the date format from my db from 'dd/mm/yyyy' to 'mm/dd/yyyy' and it works now (also is b.date - a.date)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all the data is valid, and contains the date key. Your sort function is incorrect. To sort in descending order, your sort function should look like this:

```
reviewsClone.sort(function(a,b){
        return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
      });
```

This [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) should be helpful.